# Get files information from given directory and process N file for Uploading on server simultaneously and in sequence

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics, upload, sftp

I need to process N files at a time, So I've stored all files information in `Dictionary` with `Filename, Size, and SequenceNo`, Now I've to select 5 files from that `Dictionary` and process that file, meanwhile if process for any file completed then it will select another 1 file from that dictionary.

For Example :

If I've 10 Files in the dictionary and I select the first 5 files `File 1, File 2, File 3, File 4, File 5` from the dictionary and process it. If process `File 3` is completed then the process for `File 6` should be started.

So Help me.

Thank You.

Comment: "I've stored all files in Dictionary" - why?

Comment: We need to see some code

Comment: @o-r-mapper, because I need that information after process completion. so I've stored that info.

Comment: @HirenPatel: I mean, why in a *dictionary*? Why not in a list, or a queue, or another collection structure?

Comment: @TheGeneral: Could you elaborate what code you would need to see here? Currently, no information about the current implementation seems to be missing from the question, but maybe there is a particular aspect that is unclear to you, which would be helpful for the OP to know in order to improve their question?

Comment: please provide some code.

Comment: @o-r-mapper, I need to store multiple details like Size, Name, It's Directory Name, Comments, etc so I have stored information in the dictionary.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper yeah i guess you are right, the problem is more conceptual, though i must admit, its hard to know where to start with an answer here

Comment: @HirenPatel: Bluntly put, a dictionary is the collection of choice when you have an unordered set of elements with some kind of a key, and you want to access these elements by means of the key. If you want to store and retrieve several connected values (= an object with several properties) sequentially, dictionary is not the right choice, and you should be using e.g. a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1).

Comment: @o-r-mapper, If I take List and store all information by taking an array of a string and add those array in the list, that not solve my problem for process file one by one. so help me to solve my problem.

Comment: @HirenPatel: Neither does a dictionary, but it doesn't add an additional complication. I am attempting to help you find a reasonable starting point, and make sure our understanding about this matches, before answering the concrete question.

Comment: Sounds like you should think about the Linda concurrent model and use a `ConcurrentBag` to hold your files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, @netmage I finally find my answer with the user of **ConcurrentBag** so I'll post the answer of my own question.

There is one namespace that provides several thread-safe collection classes that is  [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.8). I have used one from that namespace that is **ConcurrentBag**

Unlike **List**, A  **ConcurrentBag** bag allow modification while we are doing iteration on it. it's also thread-safe and allow concurrent access on it.

I have Implemented the following code for the solution of my problem.

I have declared **ConcurrentBag** object **FileData** as global.

```
ConcurrentBag<string[]> FileData = new ConcurrentBag<string[]>();
```

Created one function to get file information and store them into **FileData**.

```
private void GetFileInfoIntoBag(string DirectoryPath)
{
      var files = Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryPath, " *", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

      foreach (var file in files)
      {
            FileInfo f1 = new FileInfo(file);
            fileData = new string[4];
            fileData[0] = f1.Name;
            fileData[1] = GetFileSize.ToActualFileSize(f1.Length, 2);
            fileData[2] = Convert.ToString(i);
            fileData[3] = f1.FullName;
            i++;
            FileData.Add(fileData);
       }
}
```

And then on then for upload proccess, I have created **N** Task as I required and Implemented logic for upload inside them.

```
private void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Task> tskCopy = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        tskCopy.Add(Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (FileData.Count > 0)
            {
                string[] file;
                FileData.TryTake(out file);
                if (file != null && file.Count() > 3)
                {
                   /* Upload Logic*/
                    GC.Collect();
                }
            }
        }));
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tskCopy.ToArray());
    MessageBox.Show("Upload Complited Successfully");
}
```

Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you wish to process your files in a specific order, at most five at a time.

So far, information about your files is stored sequentially in a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=netframework-4.8).

One straightforward way to move across the list is to store the index of the next element to access in an `int` variable, e.g. `nextFileIndex`. You initialize it to `0`.

When starting to process one of your files, you take the information from your list:

```
MyFileInfo currentFile;
lock (myFiles)
{
    if (nextFileIndex < myFiles.Count)
    {
        currentFile = myFiles[nextFileIndex++];
    }
}
```

You start five "processes" like that in the beginning, and whenever one of them has ended, you start a new one.

Now, for these "processes" to run in parallel (it seems like that is what you intend), please read about multithreading, e.g. the [task parallel library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) that is part of .NET. My suggestion would be to create five tasks that grab the next file as long as the `nextFileIndex` has not exceeded the maximum index in the list, and use something like [`Task<TResult>.WaitAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WaitAll_System_Threading_Tasks_Task___) to wait until none of the tasks has anything to do anymore.

**Be aware of multi-threading issues.**

Comment: Thanks, But for multi threading issue I've solve my problem using ConcurrentBag.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentbag-1?view=netframework-4.8 , You can check my answer for resolving issue.